# Output result depending on a second output result to extract

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a survey app with shiny. The idea here is to give a kind of weight for each question, depending on the answer of the user (Answer 1 for question 1 is 10 points, Answer 2 for question 1 is 50 points, ...). The final result of the survey is simply the sum of all answers given by the user.

For now, my code is this one:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(   
      tags$h3("Test 1"),   
      verticalLayout(sidebarPanel(width=8,
      radioButtons(inputId = "Q1", label = "Question 1?",choices =  c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"))),
      tags$h3("Test 2"),
      sidebarPanel(width=8,
      radioButtons(inputId = "Q2", label = "Question 2?",choices =  c("Choice 4", "Choice 5", "Choice 6"))),
      actionButton(inputId="go", label="Update"),
      textOutput("result_txt"),imageOutput("result_img")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {

# Text output #
    output$result_txt <- renderText({

        Answer1 <- "Choice 1" %in% input$Q1
        Answer2 <- "Choice 2" %in% input$Q1
        Answer3 <- "Choice 3" %in% input$Q1
        
        Answer4 <- "Choice 4" %in% input$Q2
        Answer5 <- "Choice 5" %in% input$Q2
        Answer6 <- "Choice 6" %in% input$Q2
   
        if (Answer1){ resultQ1 <- 10 } 
        else if (Answer2){ resultQ1 <- 50 }
        else if (Answer3){ resultQ1 <- 100 }

        if (Answer4){ resultQ2 <- 20 } 
        else if (Answer5){ resultQ2 <- 40 }
        else if (Answer6){ resultQ2 <- 60 }

        tags$h4 <- paste("Your final result is ",resultQ1+resultQ2)
        })  
          
})          

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to extract the final result (e.g `resultQ1+resultQ2`), for using it in a second output. Depending on this result, I would like shiny to display a specific image as a second output.

It should be something like that:

```
output$result_img <- renderImage({

if(as.numeric(resultQ1+resultQ2)>=100){
png("Image1.png")} 
if(as.numeric(resultQ1+resultQ2)<100){
png("Image2.png")} 

},deleteFile=FALSE)
```

How can I display both results (numeric result and image result) at the end of my survey, and also update the results with the action button according to the user's input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and working minimal example.

We can take advantage of the radioButtons `choiceValues` to simplify our code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(   
    
    #Question 1
    tags$h3("Test 1"),   
    wellPanel(
        radioButtons(inputId = "Q1", label = "Question 1?", choiceNames = c("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"), choiceValues = c(10, 50, 100))
    ),
    
    #Question 2
    tags$h3("Test 2"),
    wellPanel(
        radioButtons(inputId = "Q2", label = "Question 2?", choiceNames = c("Choice 4", "Choice 5", "Choice 6"), choiceValues = c(20, 40, 60))
    ),

    #Action Button
    actionButton(inputId = "go", label = "Update"),
    
    #Text Output
    textOutput("result_txt"),
    
    #Image Output
    imageOutput("result_img")
    
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {
    
    #Button 'Go' is Pressed
    observeEvent(input$go, {
        
        #Text Output
        output$result_txt <- renderText({
            
            tags$h4 <- paste("Your final result is ", isolate(as.numeric(input$Q1) + as.numeric(input$Q2)))
            
        })  
        
        #Image Output
        output$result_img <- renderImage({
            
            if(isolate(as.numeric(input$Q1) + as.numeric(input$Q2) >= 100)) {
                list(src = "Image1.png")
            } else {
                list(src = "Image2.png")
            }
            
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
        
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
})          

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Also working on my side with my real inputs and outputs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the part with the image but this should work:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(   
  tags$h3("Test 1"),   
  verticalLayout(sidebarPanel(width=8,
                              radioButtons(inputId = "Q1", label = "Question 1?",choices =  c("Choice 1" = 10, "Choice 2" = 50, "Choice 3" = 100))),
                 tags$h3("Test 2"),
                 sidebarPanel(width=8,
                              radioButtons(inputId = "Q2", label = "Question 2?",choices =  c("Choice 4" = 20, "Choice 5" = 40, "Choice 6" = 60))),
                 actionButton(inputId="go", label="Update"),
                 textOutput("result_txt"),imageOutput("result_img")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    result = NULL,
    trigger = 0
  )

  observe({
    req(input$Q1)
    req(input$Q2)
    rv$result <- as.numeric(input$Q1) + as.numeric(input$Q2)
  })

  # Text output #
  output$result_txt <- renderText({
    req(rv$trigger > 1)
    rv$trigger
    tags$h4 <- paste("Your final result is ", isolate(rv$result))
  })

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    rv$trigger <- rv$trigger + 1
  })
  
  # output$result_img <- renderImage({
  #   req(rv$trigger > 1)
  #   rv$trigger
  #   
  #   if(as.numeric(isolate(rv$result))>=100){
  #     png("Image1.png")}
  #   else {
  #     png("Image2.png")}
  # 
  # },deleteFile=FALSE)
  
})          

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tested with my inputs and outputs and your code is working (including the part with the image). I just changed `png("MyImage.png")` with `list(src="MyImage.png")` and it works nice, thanks.